# Dedicated Stack Overflow for projects

Tags: feature-request

As a Chrome extension author I would like to internationalize my extension. Setting this up is easy and mechanisms are provided in an API. The problem is to find translations (I don't speak 20 languages) so it must be done by my users. You can ask your users for translations and you will probably end up with a lot of different translations for the same language so you will need to find the best one. But how to do this when you don't speak the language?

That's when it came to my mind that a structure like a question on stack overflow is ideal for this situation. I could set up a page per locale and ask my users to go to the page of their language and translate it, or upvote the one that matches best. After a while I would end up with better and better translations. And I can still make my own decision after all.

Of course I understand that stack overflow isn't built for this use case and if I would ask these questions they would be closed pretty soon. But I think there is an idea here and I am pretty sure it is applicable on other situations, where a form factor like stack overflow would be useful.

The core audience of SE websites seem to be programmers or people involved in software projects. Things like code review, translations, design ideas,... could really benefit from a structure like this.

I am thinking of something like having my own little stack overflow under my user profile where I could set up questions that are intended for the users of my extension.

Basically I would like to hear your thoughts on whether there is a market here and how you see this practically (my idea was just as an example, there are probably better solutions)

Answer (score 4):

This is a very interesting idea, but maybe not really fitting  for the Stack Exchange network. Have you considered using one of the Open Source [Stack Overflow clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) for this?

Comment: The beauty of having this as a service is that you don't have to create and manage it all by yourself so that you can concentrate more on your own project. I think there is room for SE to extend their activities.